# Concept of Naive Bayes for demonstration purposes, how to calculate word possibilities

Tags: math, probability, spam, bayesian

I need to demonstrate the Bayesian spam filter in school.

To do this I want to write a small Java application with GUI (this isn't a problem).

I just want to make sure that I really grasped the concept of the filter, before starting to write my code. So i will describe what I am going to build and how I will program it and would be really grateful if you could give a "thumbs up" or "thumbs down".

Remember: It is for a short presentation, just to demonstrate. It does not have to be performant or something else ;)

I imagine the program having 2 textareas.

In the first I want to enter a text, for example

> "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog"

I then want to have two buttons under this field with "good" or "bad".

When I hit one of the buttons, the program counts the appearances of each word in each section.

So for example, when I enter following texts:

> "hello you viagra" | bad
>
> "hello how are you" | good
>
> "hello drugs viagra" | bad

For words I do not know I assume a probability of 0.5

My "database" then looks like this:

```
<word>, <# times word appeared in bad message>

hello, 2
you, 1
viagra, 2
how, 0
are, 0
drugs, 1
```

In the second textarea I then want to enter a text to evaluate if it is "good" or "bad".

So for example:

> "hello how is the viagra selling"

The algorithm then takes the whole text apart and looks up for every word it's probability to appear in a "bad" message.

This is now where I'm stuck:

If I calculate the probability of a word to appear in a bad message by # times it appeared in bad messages / # times it appeared in all messages, the above text would have 0 probability to be in any category, because:

- how never appeared in a bad message, so probability is 0
- viagra never appeared in a good message, so probability also 0

When I now multiply the single probabilities, this would give 0 in both cases.

Could you please explain, how I calculate the probability for a single word to be "good" or "bad"?

Best regards and many thanks in advance
me

Answer (score 2):

For unseen words you would like to do [Laplace smoothing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Additive_smoothing). What does that mean: having a zero for some word count is counterintuitive since it implies that probability of this word is 0, which is false for any word you can imagine :-) Thus you want to add a little, but positive probability to every word.

Also, consider using logarithms. Long messages will have many words with probability < 1. When you multiply lots of small floating numbers on a computer you can easily run into numerical issues. In order to overcome it, you may note that:

```
log (p1 * ... * pn) = log p1 + ... + log pn
```

So we traded n multiplications of small numbers for n additions of relatively big (and negative) ones. Then you can `exp`onentiate result to obtain a probability estimate.

**UPD**: Actually, it's an interesting subtopic for your demo. It shows a drawback of NB of outputting zero probabilities and a way one can fix it. And it's not an ad-hoc patch, but a result of applying Bayesian approach (it's equivalent to adding a prior)

**UPD 2**: Didn't notice it first time, but it looks like you got Naive Bayes concept wrong. Especially, bayesian part of it.

Essentially, NB consists of 2 components:

1. We use Bayes' rule for a posterior distribution over class labels. This gives us `p(class|X) = p(X|class) p(class) / p(X)` where `p(X)` is the same for all `class`es, so it doesn't have any influence on the order of probabilities. Or, another way to say the same, is to say that `p(class|X)` is proportional to `p(X|class) p(class)` (up to a constant). As you may guessed already, that's where **Bayes** comes from.
2. The formula above does not have any model assumptions, it's a probability theory law. However, it's too hard to apply it directly since `p(X|class)` denotes probability of encountering *message* `X` in a `class`. No way we would have enough data to estimate probability of every single message possible. So here goes our model assumption: we say that words of a message are independent (which is, obviously, wrong and incorrect, thus method is **Naive**). This leads us to `p(X|class) = p(x1|class) * ... * p(xn|class)` where `n` is amount of words in `X`.

Now we need somehow estimate probabilities `p(x|class)`. `x` here is not a whole message, but just a (one) word. Intuitively, probability of getting some `word` from a given a `class` is equal to the number of occurrences of that word in that class divided by the total size of the class: `#(word, class) / #(class)` (or, we could use Bayes' rule once again: `p(x|class) = p(x, class) / p(class)`).

Accordingly, since `p(x|class)` is a distribution over `x`s, we need it to sum to 1. Thus, if we apply Laplace smoothing by saying `p(x|class) = (#(x, class) + a) / Z` where `Z` is a normalizing constant, we need to enforce the following constraint: `sum_x p(x|class) = 1`, or, equivalently, `sum_x(#(x, class) + a) = Z`. It gives us `Z = #(class) + a * N` where `N` is number of all words (just number of words, not their occurrences!)

Comment: This shouldn't be applied only to unseen words.

Comment: Hey
Thank you for your answers. Thanks to this page (which wasn't written by me!): [link](http://www.nils-haldenwang.de/computer-science/machine-learning/how-to-apply-naive-bayes-classifiers-to-document-classification-problems) I came up with the following code:

(occursIn(s, bad) + 1.0) / (occursIn(s, bad) + occursIn(s, good) + 2)

-good, bad are linkedlists with the words
-occursIn gives the # how often the word s is in the respective linkedList
-and the +1 and +2 are parameters of laplace or additive smoothing (the 2 because we have 2 categories: good and bad)

What d you guys think?
Greez

Comment: @user2399808, your formula doesn't look right to me. Please, look at my update to the answer.